# Sorting an ofile in lexicographical order

Tags: python

I made a function that takes the words that contain a `string` `'s'` from a file `'ifile'` moves them into `'ofile'`.
It works perfectly. I just need helping sorting the words that are now in `ofile` in `lexicographical` order.

Here's my code:

```
def getListContain(s,ifile,file):

 newline= ''
 for word in ifile:
     if word.find(s) != -1:
        ofile.write(newline + word.strip())
        newline = '\n'
```

Comment: Is this really the code you're using? Can you show the code that's calling the function?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know one can simply iterate over a file object to get lines out of it. Let me try to answer your question now.

Answer (score 0):

To sort a list of strings in lexicographical order you simply do:

```
listOfStrings.sort()
```

So in your case it would be:

```
def getListContain(s,ifile,file):
    listOfStrings = []
    for word in ifile:
        if word.find(s) != -1:
            listOfStrings.append(word.strip()+'\n')
    listOfStrings.sort()
    for item in listOfStrings:
        ofile.write(item)          #Based on your code, i'm assuming that 'ofile' is defined outside the function.
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Append your words to a list.

2- Sort the list.

3- Write the list to the file.

```
 word_list = []
 for word in ifile:
     if word.find(s) != -1:
        word_list.append(word.strip())
 word_list = sorted(word_list)
 ofile.write("\n".join(word_list))
```